# При парсинге сайта получаю сообщение что надо подтвердить что ты человек

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер

Пробую сделать парсер сайтов. Пока что далеко я не ушел. Возникла проблема.
Что часть когда которая у меня получилась, код файла `index.js`:

```
const needle = require('needle');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'http://example.com/login.php';

needle.get(url, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        throw (err);
    };
    const $ = cheerio.load(res.body);

    console.log($('h1').text());
    console.log($('p').text());
    console.log($('a').attr('href'));
});
```

Получаю ответ:

```
Example Domain
This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.More information...
http://www.iana.org/domains/example
```

Проблема появилась когда при парсинге сайта я получаю ответ в консоль:

```
Please verify you are a human
Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the website.

This may happen as a result of the following:

Javascript is disabled or blocked by an extension (ad blockers for example)
Your browser does not support cookies
Please make sure that Javascript and cookies are enabled on your browser and that you are not blocking them from loading.

Reference ID: #bb7cd410-8360-11e9-a0fb-d988de7d56a9
```

Можно ли обойти это и спарсить данный с сайты?

Comment: попробуйте использовать puppeteer

Comment: @Дмытрык попробовал, сделал скрин а на нем капча

Comment: Значит этот вопрос решен, а капча  это уже другая проблема

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, сервер определил что запрос идет не от клиента, а от бота по `UserAgent`.

Попробуйте заменить `UserAgent` перед вызовом `needle.get()`

```
needle.defaults({
    user_agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
});
```

Если этот способ не поможет, то сайт использует другие проверки, например JS.
В таком случае, нужно расширение имитирующее браузер, например `puppeteer`.

Comment: Не помогло, так выдало сообщение и ссылку на https://www.perimeterx.com/whywasiblocked/

Comment: При первой попытке с UserAgent по умолчанию, адрес попал в черный список. К тому же на сайте, видимо используется защита через JS, если скрипт на странице каждый раз не отрабатывает то через сколько то попыток, адрес заноситься в черный список.

Comment: Пройдите по ссылке, там все написано про PerimeterX. В вашем случае, простой парсинг страницы не подойдет. Нужно расширение имитирующее браузер, например `puppeteer`.